# Permutations, skew-symmetric forms and degeneracy

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, permutations

Define a skew-symmetric form $(\cdot,\cdot)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2k}$ by $$(e_i,e_j) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if $i<j$},\\ -1 &\text{if $i>j$},\\ 0 & \text{if $i=j$.}\end{cases}$$ Given a permutation $\pi:\{1,\dotsc, 2 k\}\to \{1,\dotsc, 2 k\}$, let $V_\pi$ be the space spanned by $e_{\pi(2i)}-e_{\pi(2i-1)}$ for $1\leq i\leq k$.

For which permutations $\pi$ is the restriction $(\cdot,\cdot)|_{V_\pi\times V_\pi}$ non-degenerate?

Comment: This is invariant under precomposition by a permutation preserving the partition $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\dots,\{2k-1,2k\}\}$, so the number of cases to check is in principle $\frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k}=1.3.5.\dots.(2k-1)$, namely, for $0\le k\le 6$: $1$, $1$, $3$, $15$, $105$, $945$, $10395$ cases ([sequence on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001147)). If one has a simple way to enumerate a transversal for the stabilizer $H_k$ of this partition in $\mathrm{Sym}(k)$, one can ask a computer and guess a pattern or typical behavior.

Comment: Note that $k$ must be even for any such $\pi$ to exist (assuming that non- degenerate means symplectic).

Comment: By non-degenerate I mean that there is no $v\in V_\pi$ such that $(v,w)=0$ for all $w\in V_\pi$.

Comment: I should say that the question here is close to a restatement of a question I asked two months ago: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330365/rank-and-frequency-of-permutations?rq=1

Comment: It is clear that the restriction will be degenerate for some $\pi$: for instance, if there's any $1\leq i\leq k$ such that $\pi(2i-1) = \pi(2 i)-1$ or $\pi(2i−1)=\pi(2i)+1$, or also if there are $1\leq i,j\leq k$ such that $\pi(2j)=\pi(2i)+1$ and $\pi(2j−1)=\pi(2i−1)−1$. Or yet again if there are $1\leq i_0,i_1,i_2\leq k$ such that $\pi(2 i_2) = \pi(2 i_1)+1 = \pi(2 i_0)+2$ and $\pi(2 i_2−1)=\pi(2 i_1−1)+1= \pi(2 i_0−1)+2$. Are there criteria like these ones describing the full answer, and making clear that the $\pi$ for which $(\cdot,\cdot)_{V_\pi\times V_\pi}$ is degenerate are "special"?

Comment: @H A Helfgott : Ok, that's what I understood. Non-degenerate skew-symmetric forms exist only in even dimension (here $k=\dim V_\pi$).

Comment: OK, good - no objection to that.

Comment: In different words, you have $k$ segments on the line with distinct endpoints, and the skew-symmetric matrix with rows and columns enumerated by them is $M([a,b],[c,d])=1, a<c<b<d$; $=-1$ if $c<a<d<b$, 0 otherwise. The question is when is it non-degenerated.

Comment: Precisely; $k$ segments on the line with distinct endpoints, all contained in $\{1,2,\dotsc,2 k\}$.

Comment: very wild guess: https://oeis.org/A035319

Comment: What is the rationale? Did you do numerics? Do you mean that this is the number of $\pi$ (with $k=2n$) for which the restriction is non-degenerate?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov : Then it is the intersection matrix (on the first homology) of the oriented surface with boundary obtained by attaching $k$ rectangular "handles" $H_{a,b}$ to the rectangle $[0,2k+1]\times[-1,0]$ on its upper boundary, intersecting it in $([a-\delta,a+\delta]\cup[b-\delta,b+\delta])\times 0$ (for small $\delta>0$, with pairs $\{a,b\}$ partitioning $\{1,2,\dots,2k\}$). It is non-degenerate iff the surface is of genus $k$. Not sure this helps though.

Comment: (I should be doing something else :-) I am not completely sure I have understood everything correctly, but this is the number of perfect matchings on $\{1,\dots,4\ell\}$ (sic!) such that the skew symmetric matrix with entries as prescribed by @FedorPetrov above has nonzero determinant, checked for $\ell=1,2,3,4$.  Unless I made a mistake, apparently there are no such matrices with nonzero determinant for perfect matchings on $k=2,6,10,\dots$ elements.

Comment: I meant genus $k/2$ in my previous comment. And this is also equivalent to the surface having only one boundary component.

Comment: Let $\sigma$ be the product of the $k$ disjoint transpositions $(a,b)$. Then the non-degeneracy is equivalent to $i\mapsto \sigma(i)+1 \pmod{2k}$ being a $2k$-cycle (this is only a rephrasing of the "one boundary component" condition). And $\sigma$ is the $\pi$-conjugate of $(12)(34)\dots(2k-1,2k)$.

Comment: Aha? Why is that?

Comment: It's just the result of following the boundary of the surface : you go from  $(i-\delta,0)$ to $(\sigma(i)+\delta,0)$ along the boundary of some handle then to $\sigma(i)+1-\delta$ (next handle). So $i\mapsto \sigma(i)+1$ encodes traveling the boundary (with $j+\delta$ also encountered). It would be the same with other choices, $\sigma(i-1)$ or $\sigma(i)-1$ which are conjugates. The counting problem seems to reduce to enumeration of the decompositions of a fixed point free involution into a product of two full cycles, cf https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X81902247

Comment: Experiments (for $k=4$ and $k=6$) suggest that, for $k$ even, the number of "good" permutations is exactly $(2k)!/(k+1)$.

Comment: In reference https://www.jstor.org/stable/2000524 (by D. M. Jackson), the formula for $e_1^{(2)}(n)$ on page 797 gives the number of $\sigma$'s as $(2k)!/(k+1)!/2^k$ (for even $k$), so the number of $\pi$'s is indeed what you write.

Comment: The rank of the skew form on $V_\pi$ is more generally given by $k+1$ minus the number $b$ of cycles of $i\mapsto\sigma(i)+1$, because one one hand it is $2g$ where $g$ is the genus of the corresponding surface $S$ (with $b$ boundary components), and on the other hand it is $2-\chi(S)-b$, where Euler characteristic is $\chi(S)=1-k$ by construction.

Comment: @H A Helfgott : I should perhaps explain why $(\cdot,\cdot)$ on $V_\pi$ represents the (opposite of) intersection form on the first homology group $H$ of $S=S_\pi$. A basis for $H$ is given by the $k$ cycles represented by simple closed curves $h_{a,b}$ going (say) clockwise around the (disjoint) handles $H_{a,b}$ (with $(a,b)=(\pi(2i-1),\pi(2i))$ one of the transpositions in $\sigma$) and closing in the big lower rectangle. Then the intersection number  $h_{a,b}\cdot h_{c,d}$ is $-M([a,b],[c,d])$ in Fedor's notation above ($-1$ if $a<c<b<d$, $1$ if $c<a<d<b$, $0$ else).

Comment: Yup, computations confirm this.

Comment: So, the wild guess was actually correct (except that the formula connecting the two things is marked as conjectural on oeis.org)!

Comment: I wonder whether it is possible to either (a) remove topology from the argument or (b) learn the required topology quickly? (It has been decades since I last looked at graduate Munkres...)

Comment: In fact all topology in this boils down to the classification of orientable surfaces, Euler characteristic, and the algebraic intersection of oriented curves on them, aka intersection product on first homology. I'm ashamed of not being able to find a suitable reference (there are plenty on the first two items, but I don't find a simple treatment of the --here crucial-- intersection product, stripped of heavy machinery), but I'm searching...

Comment: Well, it should be in graduate Munkres, no? That was the first graduate course I took (as a sophomore), so I have some vague memory of smidgens of incomplete understanding. A briefer treatment would be much appreciated, though.

Comment: Yes, this is covered in Munkres, but intersection (cup product in cohomology + Poincaré duality) doesn't come before chapters 5 and 8 (p. >250). I'll try a proper answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give it a try (clearly, comments aren't enough, and the references I found are too much).

Given the permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,2,\dots,2k\}$ one can build an orientable surface with boundary as follows.

Take a topological disk, say the rectangle $[0,2k+1]\times[0,1]$ in the complex plane, and consider its quotient by the relation which identifies for each $i=1,\dots,k$ a small interval $[a-\delta,a+\delta]$ ($0<\delta<1/2$) around point $a=\pi(2i-1)$ with interval $[b-\delta,b+\delta]$ around $b=\pi(2i)$, *with orientation reversed*, that is $a+x\simeq b-x$.

[added: this is reversed from my comments under the question : here we glue things on the *bottom* edge of the rectangle. This has the purely cosmetic effect of numbering points in the usual --counterclockwise-- orientation of the boundary].

The result is a compact, connected, *orientable* surface with boundary, which you can picture in $3$-space by protruding "nearly horizontal" rectangles from the identified intervals, making them meet only in their tips and the prescribed pair (I'm really sorry for not being able to draw that here, and being probably very bad at describing mental pictures too). The orientation comes from projection to the horizontal plane.

The resulting surface $S_\pi$ depends only on the partition of $\{1,2,\dots,2k\}$ into the pairs $\{\pi(2i-1),\pi(2i)\}$, $i=1,\dots,k$, that is on the $\pi$-conjugate $\sigma$ of the involution $\sigma_0=(12)(34)\dots(2k-1)(2k)$. There are $k!2^k$ different $\pi$'s for one $\sigma$ (this amounts to what @Ycor said in a comment).

Let $b$ be the number of boundary components of $S_\pi$. A book-keeping exercise
tells you that $b$ is the number of cycles of the permutation $i\mapsto \sigma(i)+1$
(or its inverse $i\mapsto\sigma(i-1)$, or any of their conjugates, like $i\mapsto\sigma(i)-1$, that's the same number).

Now the all powerful surface classification theorem tells us that this (compact, connected, orientable) $S_\pi$ is (homeomorphic to) an (orientable) surface of some genus $g$ with the interiors of $b$ disjoint closed discs removed.

Why that ? Well, glue $b$ closed discs to the boundary components of $S_\pi$, and you have a (compact, connected, orientable) surface *without boundary*, connected sum of $g$ tori, by [classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Classification_of_closed_surfaces). Then undo.

Hence the amazing fact : there is only one model for each pair $(g,b)$ !
[this should be a footnote] That this is amazing may easily be overlooked nowadays, but can perhaps better be sensed by the fact that *mapping class groups* of surfaces, that is the discrete groups of components of their autoequivalences (homeo/diffeo doesn't matter here) aren't yet understood. For instance they share many properties with subgroups of linear groups, but they are not known to be linear aside from small cases. Yet they are the means to recognize a surface when we meet one.[end footnote]

Now in an oriented manifold $M^n$, one can count algebraically intersections of submanifolds or *cycles* of complementary dimensions, as Poincaré tolds us. Either triangulate and refine or use Thom's transversality, but in the end it's linear algebra, counting intersections by comparing the orientation of the direct sum of tangent spaces with the ambient one. This gives rise to the integer valued *intersection product* on cycles of complementary dimensions $p,q=n-p$, which depends only on their homology classes and is $(-1)^{pq}$-symmetric.

Crucially, it is *non-degenerate* when the manifold is *closed* (and oriented), meaning that $H_p(M,\mathbb{Z})$ mod torsion is isomorphic to $Hom(H_{n-p}(M,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$ via the intersection product. This is part of so-called *Poincaré duality*, expressed more neatly nowadays by adding *co*homology to the picture (but we don't need it).

In our context of $1$-cycles on oriented surfaces, intersection is skew-symmetric.

If $S_g$ is a closed (=without boundary), connected oriented surface of genus $g$, $H_1(S_g,\mathbb{Z})$ is a free abelian group with a non-degenerate skew-symmetric form, with standard "symplectic" basis $(a_1,b_1,\dots,a_g,b_g)$, meaning

$$a_i\cdot b_j=\delta_{ij},$$ $$a_i\cdot a_j=b_i\cdot b_j = 0.$$

But when there are $b\geq 1$ boundary components, $H_1(S_{g,b},\mathbb{Z})\simeq \mathbb{Z}^{2g+b-1}$, mapping to $H_1(S_g,\mathbb{Z})\simeq \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ with kernel of rank $b-1$, preserving (clearly) the intersection form. [added comment] This could be proved using the homology exact sequence of the pair $(S_g \supset S_{g,b})$, but here it is simpler to use homotopy invariance of homology plus the fact that for $b>0$, $S_{g,b}$  is homotopy equivalent to the graph with one vertex and $2g+b-1$ loops.
This is also relevant below.

Hence the intersection form is non-degenerate on $H_1(S_{g,b},\mathbb{Z})$ iff $b\leq 1$.

Concerning the surface $S_\pi$, it should be clear that it is homotopy equivalent to a graph with one vertex and $k$ loops, and
that letting  $h_i$ denote the class of a closed curve going *counterclockwise* [NOTE: this is reversed from my comments under the question] through the handle resulting from gluing the intervals $\pi(2i-1)\pm\delta$ to $\pi(2i)\mp\delta$ (in reverse) that

- the $h_i$, $i=1,\dots, k$ form a basis of $H_1(S_\pi,\mathbb{Z})\simeq\mathbb{Z}^k$
- the matrix of their intersection products is the same as your skew-symmetric form on $V_\pi$

(maybe up to sign, I switched to the upper half plane hoping to correct for this).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! A couple of comments. First, you are identifying segments of the top edge. This fact was more clearly stated in your original comments - reading your answer I was a bit confused at first.

Comment: Second, by "closed curve" you mean "closed curve traversed clockwise" (this seems obvious but is unstated).

Comment: Also used is the fact that the h_i's form a basis of the homology. That much seems evident - I take it is not customary to say more than that?

Comment: Also, quick double-check. All of the above looks as if it would still be valid in homology over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, $H_1(S_g,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\sim (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{2g}$ (I imagine). Thus even the rank over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ of the matrix $M$ is as stated.

Comment: Oh, and the Euler characteristic of the surface without boundary is $1+b-k$ by triangulation, so its genus $g$ is $(1+k-b)/2$. (Just spelling out what you spelled out before.)

Comment: Sorry for the top/bottom switch. I tried to get the signs right and use standard orientation on the boundary, but ended up in confusing you (and forgetting to orient the curves $h_i$)... I'll try to fix this. And add something more convincing for the fact that $h_i$ form a basis. You are also right about mod 2 coefficients.

Comment: To @BS.  Can you contact me by email so that we can put you in the acknowledgments?

Comment: Sorry but my purpose here isn't to collect recognition, only to try to help. I'm happy that sometimes I succeed.